# How do I refresh a stale Selenium element if I don't have the original XPath

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

Is there a way (If using Java) to refresh an existing element that has become stale. Something like, I have an Angular app that removes and re-adds an element. Sometimes this hits a race condition and gives me a stale state. I would like to avoid a sleep to slow things down, however, I am fine with something that tries every 500 ms or something. I see foundBy but when I try something like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(element.foundBy))
```

But this doesn't work. How do I refresh if I am not sure what xPath was initially used?

Comment: Have you tried using ExpectedCondition with WebDriverWait - visibilityOf(WebElement) - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement- You can set the polling time and timeout in WebDriverWait constructor.

Comment: So what if it is on the page, but requires a scroll to be visible? Also how do I refresh the element if it is stale and I don't have the original query used to grab it last time.

Comment: Store your XPATH in a string and carry it along with you as you go. I mean to declare the string at the global level. If you deal with instance which may cause stale, we may use the string to construct the fresh webelement.

Comment: It isn't that easy since the xpath is limited to another xpath that is limited to another xpath and it is hard to make sure I have all the right xpaths just right

Answer (score 2):

In case of page refresh or any change in DOM that includes your WebElement will lead to such exception. Selenium doesn't support WebElement refresh (sadly enough) so you have to locate your element again by hand, which may be pita in some cases. I use

```
public WebElement refreshElement(WebElement element){
    String sElement = element.toString().split("-> ")[1];
    String locatorType = sElement.split(": ")[0];
    if (locatorType.matches("css selector")) locatorType = "css";
    String loc0 = sElement.split(": ")[1];
    String theLocator = loc0.substring(0,loc0.length()-1);
    System.out.println("Refreshing element with "+locatorType+": "+theLocator);

    return locator.getElement(theLocator,locatorType);
}
```

and seems to work fine since a WebElement.toString() will produce something like

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (****************************)] -> locatortype: locator]
```

The getElement method goes like

```
public WebElement getElement(String locator, String type) {
    if (type.equals("id")) {
        return this.driver.findElement(By.id(locator));
    }
    else if (type.equals("name")) {
        return this.driver.findElement(By.name(locator));
    }
etc...
}
```

Comment: I was looking into doing something like this. However, if your WebElement was obtained with a findElements (with an S) call. The resulting toString() does not describe the index of the item you selected. 

Just saying it doesn't work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I could get over StaleElementReferenceException by extracting the locator value and refreshing the element.

```
    /*
     * Example Element Info: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (7066c356a66e3d36c02336042e9ae3bd)] -> tag name: input] 
     * Get locator value from Element and find again to get over StaleElementReferenceException
     */
    public WebElement refreshWebElement(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement webEl) {
        String elementInfo = webEl.toString();
        elementInfo = elementInfo.substring(elementInfo.indexOf("->"));
        String elementLocator = elementInfo.substring(elementInfo.indexOf(": "));
        elementLocator = elementLocator.substring(2, elementLocator.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(elementInfo);

        WebElement retWebEl = null;
        if (elementInfo.contains("-> link text:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.linkText(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> name:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.name(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> id:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.id(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> xpath:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> class name:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.className(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> css selector:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> partial link text:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(elementLocator));
        } else if (elementInfo.contains("-> tag name:")) {
            retWebEl = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName(elementLocator));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No valid locator found. Couldn't refresh element");
        }
        return retWebEl;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like below:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath here"));

FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(yourElement )));
```

Comment: This doesn't do much. You are waiting for the located element to be not stale, which is the same as waiting for an element that is already present to be present. With the current implementation of Selenium there's no way to recover from a stale state without calling `findElement` again.